# I want the column which has NULL in my database table to make it blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure created in sql server 2008 wherein the columns from two different tables in the same database are displayed. I want to replace the NULL value in my column to blank. Can anyone help me in this?

```
    AlTER PROCEDURE sp_Test123  --sp_Test123
AS
BEGIN
SELECT MediaContentType.MediaContentTypeID as ID, 
MediaContentType.FileExtension,
IQCategory.Description,IQSubCategory.IQSubDesription
FROM MediaContentType
LEFT JOIN IQCategory
ON MediaContentType.MediaContentTypeID =IQCategory.IQCategoryID
LEFT JOIN IQSubCategory
ON MediaContentType.MediaContentTypeID = IQSubCategory.IQSubCategoryID

END
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Post some code? And is it in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to replace `Null` value in your query then it is very easy.

You have to use `IsNull` function.

Like

```
SELECT MediaContentType.MediaContentTypeID as ID, 
ISNULL(MediaContentType.FileExtension,'') as FileExtension,
ISNULL(IQCategory.Description,'') as Description
ISNULL(IQSubCategory.IQSubDesription,'') as IQSubDesription
FROM MediaContentType
LEFT JOIN IQCategory
ON MediaContentType.MediaContentTypeID =IQCategory.IQCategoryID
LEFT JOIN IQSubCategory
ON MediaContentType.MediaContentTypeID = IQSubCategory.IQSubCategoryID
```

If you want to update the null value in your table then use update statement.

Like

```
Update MyTable
Set MyNullColumn = ''
where MyNullColumn Is Null
```

Comment: its not a table its a store procedure. so how do i select the column from that sp?

Comment: Use IsNull function in your query inside SP.

Comment: i have posted my SP, can you please tell me how do i do that?